# How do I convert an NSString to an integer using Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsstring

I need to convert an [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/intValue) to an integer in Swift:   Here's the current code I'm using; it doesn't work:

```
 var variable = (NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
 exampeStruct.otherVariable = (variable).intValue
```

Variable is a normal varable, and exampleStruct is a struct elsewhere in the code with a subvariable otherVariable.

I expect it to set `exampleStruct.otherVariable` to an `int` value of the `NSString`, but I get the following error:

```
"Cannot convert the expression's type () to type Float"
```

How do I convert an `NSString` to `int` in Swift?

Comment: What about a quick look at the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/intValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit/update:**

No need to use NSString when coding with Swift. You can use Swift native String(data:) initializer and then convert the string to Int:

```
if let variable = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
    let integer = Int(variable) {
    exampeStruct.otherVariable = integer
}
```

If other variable is a `Float` type:

```
if let variable = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
    let integer = Float(variable) {
    exampeStruct.otherVariable = integer
}
```

Comment: toInt() function removed in Swift 2. We have to use the constructor of int which accepts a string - Int(myString). Please refer this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30739522/878414

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the problem might not be the Int conversion, but rather that the exampleStruct is expecting a Float.

If that's not the issue however (and granted, Xcode errors for Swift often seem to be more about the line number rather than about the actual problem) then something like this should work for you?

```
var ns:NSString = "1234"
if let i = (ns as String).toInt() {
    exampleStruct.otherVariable = i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you already got your answer, but I just want to explain what (I think) might not be trivial

First, we have some `NSData` we want to convert to `NSString`, because no one guaranties the data is a valid UTF8 buffer, it return an optional

```
 var variable = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Which means `variable: NSString?`

Usually `NSString` is bridged to swift's `String`, but in this case, we use an `NSString` constructor - you can think about it more as a "Foundation"-like syntax that wasn't directly imported to swift (as there's no bridge for `NSData`)

we can still use the 'Foundation' way with `NSString`

```
if let unwrappedVariable = variable {
    var number = unwrappedVariable.intValue
}
```

if `number` is a `Float`, but the string is a string representation of an integer

```
if let unwrappedVariable = variable {
    var number: Float = Float(unwrappedVariable.intValue)
}
```

if both `number` and the string (representation of) are floats:

```
if let unwrappedVariable = variable {
    var number:Float = unwrappedVariable.floatValue
}
```

Anyway, there's a small problem with using Foundation. For these types of conversions it has no concept of an optional value (for int, float). It will return 0 if it cannot parse a string as and integer or float. That's why it's better to use swift native `String`:

```
if let variable: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    if let integer = variable.toInt() {
        var integerNumber = integer
        var floatNumber = Float(integer)
    }
}
```