# NSString to Array Integer Swift Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, nsstring, xcode6

I am making a program in Swift using Multipeer Connectivity to send information between devices. I am sending a array with integers which I need to convert it to NSDictionary, but when I am trying to get it back to a integer array i can't manage to get it back. I know it's a way to convert NSString to Integer see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662471/how-do-i-convert-an-nsstring-to-an-integer-using-swift/), but i can't find a way for arrays. Does anyone know how I can do it?

My code in the peer that sends information looks like this:

```
let numberArray:[Int] = [4,76,23,65,23,75,23,65,12]

let messageDict = ["newNumbersArray":numberArray]        
let messageData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(messageDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

var error:NSError?

appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(messageData, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable, error: &error)
```

In the other peer my code looks like this:

```
func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as Dictionary
    let receivedData:NSData = userInfo["data"] as NSData

    let message = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as NSDictionary
}
```

How can I convert it back to array with int?

Comment: What actually are you trying to do? share your some code here.

Comment: in the receiving code, log message and show it here.

Comment: `{ nyeTall1 = (51,39,47,53,40,68,25,13,48 );
}` Just new line for each of the numbers

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches to sending information "over the wire" between different systems: the first is called serialization and the second is called marshaling.

**Serialization:**

The information is encoded into a wire format following a convention. In modern Cocoa the most common kinds of serialization are plist and JSON.

**Marshaling:**

Marshaling is similar to serialization, except that it allows overriding the default behavior using a mapping file. This is useful for ***contract first*** development where the aim is to try to keep the information format as stable as possible overtime, even if internally the system may change structure. Otherwise one change would mean all subscribers to a service would need to change as well.

There's also an informal approach as you're doing. But why not try instead serializing your dictionary to wire-format using:

```
let dictionary : Dictionary = ["newNumbersArray":numberArray]   
let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: nil, error: nil)
let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

And to go back from JSON at the other peer:

```
var dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Dictionary
```

Otherwise if you wanted to continue with the informal approach to serialization, you'd just loop through each item in the collection, convert it from string to integer, and add the result to another array. The [Underscore.m](http://underscorem.org) library provides a mapping function so that you can do this with a little less code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still not done, then try this

```
func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as Dictionary
    let receivedData:NSData = userInfo["data"] as NSData

    let message = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    //--
    let arr = message.objectForKey("newNumbersArray") as NSMutableArray;

    for (var i:Int = 0; i<arr.count; i++)
    {
        let n = arr[i] as Int;
        NSLog("Value : %d", n);
    }
}
```