# .toInt() removed in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, swift2

I was working on an application that used a text field and translated it into an integer. Previously my code

```
textField.text.toInt()
```

worked. Now Swift declares this as an error and is telling me to do

```
textField.text!.toInt()
```

and it says there is no `toInt()` and to try using `Int()`. That doesn't work either. What just happened?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

In Swift 2.x, the `.toInt()` function was removed from `String`. In replacement, `Int` now has an initializer that accepts a `String`

```
Int(myString)
```

In your case, you could use `Int(textField.text!)` insted of `textField.text!.toInt()`

**Swift 1.x**

```
let myString: String = "256"
let myInt: Int? = myString.toInt()
```

**Swift 2.x, 3.x**

```
let myString: String = "256"
let myInt: Int? = Int(myString)
```

Comment: how exactly would I put this to use? mine is .text.toInt() I don't actually have any text there, what would I put inside the Int() ?

Comment: @AmitNivedanKalra You could use `Int(.text)`

Comment: @Jojodmo you should avoid forcing unwrapping. You should use let myInt = Int(myString) ?? 0

Comment: I explicitly told it to do Int(lolField.text!) that did the trick.

Comment: The problem with `Int(textField.text!)` is that if `textField.text` is `nil` then you get an error.

Comment: @alondono If you don't know what the input will be, you can use `Int(textField.text ?? "0") ?? 0`

Comment: @Jojodmo Why did you use myInt: Int? when you know your input is a string from line above. Wouldn't this be enough? let myInt = Int(myString). I am just trying to understand.

Comment: @SamB Int(String) is a failable initializer. Although you do know the input string and using Int("256")! would be fine, for the sake of example it isn't unwrapped, because in reality you won't know if the input is a number or not

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 2

```
let myString: NSString = "123"
let myStringToInt: Int = Int(myString.intValue)
```

declare your string as an object NSString
and use the intValue getter

Comment: well you have that solution but, i am an objective-c developer as well and for me is so familiar use NS object, but your idea is cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its easy enough to create your own extension method to put this back in:

```
extension String {
    func toInt() -> Int? {
        return Int(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issued in Payment processing apps.
Swift 1.0

```
let expMonth = UInt(expirationDate[0].toInt()!)
let expYear = UInt(expirationDate[1].toInt()!)
```

After in Swift 2.0

```
let expMonth = Int(expirationDate[0])
let expYear = Int(expirationDate[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

**That gave me some errors too!**

This code solved my errors

```
let myString: String = dataEntered.text!  // data entered in textField
var myInt: Int? = Int(myString)    // conversion of string to Int

myInt = myInt! * 2  // manipulating the integer sum,difference,product, division 

finalOutput.text! = "\(myInt)"  // changes finalOutput label to myInt
```