# toInt() function in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

I got trouble with that when I convert from String to Int in swift 2

```
func sendNoticeTo(aptNumber aptNumber: Int) {

}

func findApt (aptNumber : String ) -> String? {
let aptNumbers = ["101","202","303","404"]
for tempAptNumber in aptNumbers {
    if ( tempAptNumber == aptNumber) {
        return aptNumber
    }
}

if let culprit = findApt("101")?.toInt() {
sendNoticeTo(aptNumber: culprit)
}
```

Swift say that function isn't available and I searched that problem but those didn't help.

Comment: try `Int(findApt("101"))` or `findApt("101") as! Int`

Comment: ya your question is good and used in future also

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739460/toint-removed-in-swift-2

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 2.0** its changed  from `toInt()` to `int()`

**Upto Swift 1.2**

```
let str: String = "101"
let myInt: Int? = str.toInt()
```

we use like

```
if let culprit = findApt("101")?.toInt() {
sendNoticeTo(aptNumber: culprit)
}
```

**Swift 2.0 & above**

```
let str: String = "101"
let myInt: Int? = Int(str)
```

so use

```
if let culprit = Int(findApt("101"))  // or use like findApt("101") as! Int
{
sendNoticeTo(aptNumber: culprit)
}
```

Comment: I tried that method before i ask but it still show error so i edit my post and post all codes. Thanks your time.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2 `toInt()` got replaced by `int()` and this works:

```
Int("222") // -> 2
```

Or to match your example:

```
Int(findApt("101")) // -> 101
```

Comment: I tried that method before i ask but it still show error so i edit my post and post all codes. Thanks your time.