# Swift 1.0 converting string to int error

Tags: string, xcode6, int, swift2

This code worked fine in swift 1.0 except when I tried to run it with swift 2.0 it gave me an error..... Can someone explain why swift is giving me this error and tell me how to fix it?
(I've already did some digging on stack overflow to try to find the solution but couldn't find it)

Thanks!! heres the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {@IBOutlet var guess: UITextField!





@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!


@IBAction func guessButton(sender: AnyObject) {




    var randomnumber = arc4random_uniform(6)


    var guessInt = guess.text!.toInt()


    if guessInt != nil {


        if Int(randomnumber) == guessInt {

            label.text = "correct"


        } else {

            label.text = "nope it wsa \(randomnumber)"

        }





    } else {


        label.text = "enter a number"


    }


    print(guess.text)








}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: what error are you getting?now the "toInt" can just be changed to Int(value)

Comment: Im getting toInt is unavailable use int initializer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.toInt() removed in Swift 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739460/toint-removed-in-swift-2)

Comment: they removed toInt in swift2. change it to Int(guess.text)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what error message you're getting, but one thing I see wrong is the following:

```
var guessInt = guess.text!.toInt()
```

You should use  `Int(value)` instead.  You can also initialize your `guessInt` in an if string to check if the value is nil:

```
if let guessInt = Int(guess.text!) {

    //Do things

} else {

    //Value was nil

}
```