# fatal error: unwrapping optional value when converting from string to INT

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm trying to convert string to Int in the below code: How Can I change the below code that converts string to Int so that the app doesn't crash?

```
    cell!.shouldEnableLikeButton(false)

    let liked: Bool = cell!.likeButton.selected
    cell?.setLikeStatus(liked)

    let originalButtonTitle = cell?.likeLabel!.text

    var likeCount: Int = originalButtonTitle!.toInt()! //This is where I get the error.. how can this be changed?

    if liked {
        likeCount += 1
    } else {
        likeCount -= 1
    }

    cell!.likeLabel.text = "\(likeCount)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.toInt() removed in Swift 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739460/toint-removed-in-swift-2)

Answer (score 1):

You can unwrap it with if let by checking that your cell's title is convertible to `Int` or not this way:

```
let originalButtonTitle = cell.textLabel?.text

if let likeCount = Int(originalButtonTitle!) {   //Int(originalButtonTitle!) will convert your String to Int.
    let wrappedCount = likeCount
    print(wrappedCount)
}
```

Now it will not crash if any values are not convertible into `Int` from `String`.

Answer (score 0):

`toInt()` function is deprecated in Swift2. Use:

```
if let likeCount = Int(originalButtonTitle)! {   
    let myVar = likeCount
}
```

Comment: Hi , i tried this but it's givingme an error "cannot find an initializer for type "int" that accepts an argument list of type '(string)'