# Swift userInput.toInt() error?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code:

```
let answer = randomIntBetween(1, high: 100)

print("Enter a number between 1 and 100!")

let userInput = input()
let inputAsInt = userInput.toInt()

if let guess = inputAsInt {
if (guess > answer) {
    print("Your guess was too high!")
} else if (guess < answer) {
    print("Your guess was too low!")
} else {
    print("You got it dead on! The answer was \(answer)!")
}
} else {
print("Not a valid answer, try adding a number!")
}
```

I am following a guide (only been learning for about a month) and I know .toInt() was removed but what would I need to put in its place?

Comment: try Int(intAsString)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739460/toint-removed-in-swift-2

Answer (score 0):

Down cast replaced it.

```
let inputAsInt = Int(userInput)
```