# swift 2.2, how to get input from text field

Tags: swift2

pardon me for beginner's question, I took this piece of code straight out of an online tutorial, didn't compile, I guess the course is outdated (my swift version is 2.2)

```
var years = edtYears.text.toInt();
```

It always complain something like `Value of optional type String? not unwrapped`, I tried to put `?` in already, still no luck. Any tip, thanks

Comment: Really outdated. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30739460/6541007).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let years = Int(edtYears.text ?? "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it doing the same thing, this will do:

```
var years = Int(edtYears.text!)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
var years = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         years = yourTextField.text
         print(years)
}
```

so this is for string

and now for Int :

```
var years = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     years = Int(yourTextField.text!)
     print("\years")
}
```

Comment: The original code converted the string to an Int. This will keep the text a String.

Comment: yes that's right ! to convert  in In Int he will have to use this:                                  var years = Int()


override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         years = Int(yourTextField.text!)
         print("\(years)")
}